# Keeping track of an array of components

Tags: vue.js

I have a really simple Vue app:

```
<div id="app">

  <item v-for="item in items" v-bind:title="item.title" v-bind:price="item.price"
        @added="updateTotal(item)"></item>

  <total v-bind:total="total"></total>

</div>
```

And a Vue instance:

```
Vue.component('item',{
  'props' : ['title', 'price'],
  'template' : "<div class='item'><div>{{ title }} – ${{total}} </div><button class='button' @click='add'>Add</button></div>",
  'data' : function(){
    return {
      quantity : 0
    }
  },
  'computed' : {
    total : function(){
      return (this.quantity * this.price).toFixed(2);
    }
  },
  methods : {
    add : function(){
      this.quantity ++;
      this.$emit('added');
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('total', {
  'props' : ['total'],
  'template' : "<div class='total'>Total: ${{ total }}</div>",

});

var app = new Vue({
  'el' : '#app',
  'data' : {
    'total' : 0,
    'items': [
      {
        'title': 'Item 1',
        'price': 21
      }, {
        'title': 'Item 2',
        'price': 7
      }
    ],
  },
  methods : {
    'updateTotal' : function(item){
      console.log('updating');
      this.total += item.price;
    }
  }
});
```

Demo link:
https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/rmezQq?editors=1010

And what I'd like to do is update the `<total>` component as the various items are added to the cart. I have it working at the moment, however it doesn't seem very elegant.

Right now, I add the price of each item to a total. What I'd really like to do is have the total as a computed property, and then every time an item component is changed, loop through them all adding the quantity * price of each. Is there a way I can do this?

One option I have come up with just now is replacing my `updateTotal` method in the main app to the below:

```
methods : {
  'updateTotal' : function(item){
    item.quantity += 1;
  }
},
computed : {       total : function(){
    var t = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i ++){
      t += this.items[i].quantity * this.items[i].price;
    }
    return t;
  }
}
```

So, beginning to store the quantity of each item inside the Vue app, not the component. But it makes more sense to store the quantity of each item inside its own component... doesn't it? What is the best way of handling this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe counter-intuitively, the components only need their data as props. The items (as data objects) are defined in the parent; just define `quantity` there, too. Then use those data items in the components, but make changes via events to the parent.

With an array that includes the quantities, it's easy to create the computed total you want.

```js
Vue.component('item', {
  'props': ['item'],
  'template': "<div class='item'><div>{{ item.title }} – ${{total}} </div><button class='button' @click='add'>Add</button></div>",
  'computed': {
    total: function() {
      return (this.item.quantity * this.item.price).toFixed(2);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    add: function() {
      this.$emit('added');
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('total', {
  'props': ['total'],
  'template': "<div class='total'>Total: ${{ total }}</div>",

});

var app = new Vue({
  'el': '#app',
  'data': {
    'items': [{
      'title': 'Item 1',
      'price': 21,
      'quantity': 0
    }, {
      'title': 'Item 2',
      'price': 7,
      'quantity': 0
    }],
  },
  computed: {
    total() {
      return this.items.reduce((a, b) => a + (b.price * b.quantity), 0).toFixed(2);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateTotal(item) {
      ++item.quantity;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <item v-for="item in items" v-bind:item="item" @added="updateTotal(item)"></item>

  <total v-bind:total="total"></total>

</div>
```